# After solving binary programing problem the constrait is violated

Tags: optimization, binary-programming

I have a binary programing problem of the form:

The input variable of this optimization problem is matrix $X$ that its entries are just $0$ or $1$, it is a $N \times M$ matrix. $t$ is the objective function that is connected to input variable through constraint (1). $\beta_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ are two $N \times M$ constant matrices. $B_{min}$ is a constant scalar.

In order to solve this problem, I use Lagrangian multipliers to get the dual problem of this primal problem.

The final solution of the primal violates the constraint (2), the result of nested sum is much higher than $B_{min}$. It seems that the solver completely ignores constraint (2) of the primal.

I want to know if there are mathematical problems with my approach that I get this result.

Comment: Lagrangian relaxations do not ensure feasibility. If you absolutely want a feasible solution, solve the dual sub problem by column generation instead.

Comment: OK. Can you briefly describe column generation?

Comment: Thats a big one...basically column generation is a procedure which dynamically generates potential "interesting" variables for your problem. It requires reformulating your problem with a change of variables in which the initial variables are expressed as convex combinations of the extreme points of the convex hull generated by a subset of your constraints. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_generation for more details.

Comment: What is interesting is the link with Lagrangian relaxation, rather than the technical details. Both methods achieve the same result differently: both iteratively solve the same subproblem to feed a master problem; the Lagrangian solves it (the master problem) with methods such as the sub gradient algorithm, column generation solves it (more precisely its dual) with linear programming.